# Running executables concurrently in Python

Tags: python, executable

I have 3 folders, namely, `1`, `2`, `3` each with the following executable. How can I run all of them concurrently at once?

```
exec(open("Test.py").read())
```

Comment: You want to run them all within the master python file? Or should they be separate processes?

Comment: I want to run them separately. It's the same file name but in different folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to run these .py files as separate processes, you should be able to execute them via the same python executable your main script is using. Use `Popen` to start all of the processes and then wait on them in turn.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys
import subprocess as subp

folder_names = ["1", "2", "3"]
procs = [subp.Popen([sys.executable, os.path.join(folder, "Test.py"])
    for folder in folder_names]
for proc in procs:
    return_code = proc.wait()
```

Comment: Where should I save this file? I don't want to put in the folders: ```1,2,3```.

Comment: Ideally you'd make it an executable (I added a "shebang" for unix like operating systems - plus you'd do `chmod +x myfile.py`. For windows, as long as .py is associated with python, it'll work). Then, put it somewhere in the operating system PATH so you can execute it from anywhere.